# having a property as a function in an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects, all of them with the same properties, but one of those properties should be a function, that decides if the object is “visible” or not

Something like:

```js
let ObjArr = [{
  name: 'Charles',
  age: 30,
  visible: (aName, anAge) => {
    return (((this.name === aName) && (this.age === anAge)) ? true : false)
  }
}]

console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Charles', 30)) // It should be true
console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Peter', 30)) // It should be false
console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Charles', 25)) // It should be false too
```

Currently, all of them say false, but the first should be true

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: `visible: (aName, anAge) => {` -> `visible(aName, anAge) {`

Comment: arrow functions have lexical `this`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: besides your question: `return this.name === aName && this.age === anAge;` the rest is just bloat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fat-arrow functions (i.e. `=>`), the `this` reference is "lexical". It means that the `this` reference points to whatever `this` was when `objArr` was defined. Whatever that object is, it probably doesn't have the `name` or `age` properties, which means that `this.name` is `undefined`, and so is `this.age`, so your comparisons both yield `false`.

To make the function take `this` reference from whatever object it was called "from" (or "on"), declare it using the `function` keyword:

```js
let ObjArr = [{
  name: 'Charles',
  age: 30,
  visible: function(aName, anAge) {
    return (((this.name === aName) && (this.age === anAge)) ? true : false)
  }
}]

console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Charles', 30)) // It should be true
console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Peter', 30)) // It should be false
console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Charles', 25)) // It should be false too
```

Alternatively, you can use the "method" syntax:

```
let ObjArr = [{
  name: 'Charles',
  age: 30,
  visible(aName, anAge) {
    return (((this.name === aName) && (this.age === anAge)) ? true : false)
  }
}]
```

It will have the same effect.

---

Bonus pointer: if you have a boolean value `x`, then expression `x ? true : false` is equivalent to just `x`. This means that your function could be:

```
  function(aName, anAge) {
    return (this.name === aName) && (this.age === anAge)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an arrow function if you want to use the `this` reference; however, you can use a [method definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

```js
let ObjArr = [{
  name: 'Charles',
  age: 30,
  visible(aName, anAge){
    return (((this.name === aName) && (this.age === anAge)) ? true : false)
  }
}]

console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Charles', 30)) // It should be true
console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Peter', 30)) // It should be false
console.log(ObjArr[0].visible('Charles', 25)) // It should be false too
```